# Insertar más registros dentro de un archivo XML

Tags: php, xml

Hola buenos días estoy creando un archivo XML donde ya tengo la estructura básica, pero ahora lo que estoy intentando es que por medio de un ciclo pueda yo ingresar mas etiquetas `<add>` debajo de la que ya se a creado hasta completar el fin del ciclo, pero lo que me esta haciendo es crear la etiqueta dentro de la que ya se creó.

Les comparto mi código que tengo hasta ahora.

> Código

```
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement('<ZohoCreator/>');

            $list = $sxe->addChild('applicationlist');

            $application = $sxe->addChild('application');
            $application->addAttribute('name', 'zoho-cdr');

            $form_list = $sxe->addChild('formlist');

            $form = $sxe->addChild('form');
            $form->addAttribute('name', 'Detalle_de_Llamada1');

            for ($i=0; $i < 3; $i++) { 
                $add = $sxe->addChild('add');

                $id_cliente = $sxe->addChild('field', 'dato1');
                $id_cliente->addAttribute('name', 'id_CLIENTE');

                $razon_social = $sxe->addChild('field', 'dato2');
                $razon_social->addAttribute('name', 'RAZON_SOCIAL');
            }

            echo $sxe->asXML();
```

> Resultado de mi código

```
<zohocreator>
    <applicationlist>
        <application name="zoho-cdr">
            <formlist>
                <form name="Detalle_de_Llamada1">
                    <add>
                        <field name="id_CLIENTE">2868</field>
                        <field name="RAZON_SOCIAL">val_RAZON_SOCIAL</field>
                        <add>
                            <field name="id_CLIENTE">2868</field>
                            <field name="RAZON_SOCIAL">val_RAZON_SOCIAL</field>
                            <add>
                                <field name="id_CLIENTE">2868</field>
                                <field name="RAZON_SOCIAL">val_RAZON_SOCIAL</field>
                            </add>
                        </add>
                    </add>
                </form>
            </formlist>
        </application>
    </applicationlist>
</zohocreator>
```

> Resultado que necesito

```
<zohocreator>
    <applicationlist>
        <application name="zoho-cdr">
            <formlist>
                <form name="Detalle_de_Llamada1">
                    <add>
                        <field name="id_CLIENTE">2868</field>
                        <field name="RAZON_SOCIAL">val_RAZON_SOCIAL</field>
                    </add>
                    <add>
                        <field name="id_CLIENTE">2868</field>
                        <field name="RAZON_SOCIAL">val_RAZON_SOCIAL</field>
                    </add>
                    <add>
                        <field name="id_CLIENTE">2868</field>
                        <field name="RAZON_SOCIAL">val_RAZON_SOCIAL</field>
                    </add>
                </form>
            </formlist>
        </application>
    </applicationlist>
</zohocreator>
```

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement('<ZohoCreator/>');

            $list = $sxe->addChild('applicationlist');

            $application = $sxe->addChild('application');
            $application->addAttribute('name', 'zoho-cdr');

            $form_list = $sxe->addChild('formlist');

            $form = $sxe->addChild('form');
            $form->addAttribute('name', 'Detalle_de_Llamada1');

            for ($i=0; $i < 3; $i++) { 
                $add = $form[$i]->addChild('add');

                $id_cliente = $add->addChild('field', $id_CLIENTE);
                $id_cliente->addAttribute('name', 'id_CLIENTE');

                $razon_social = $add->addChild('field', 'val_RAZON_SOCIAL');
                $razon_social->addAttribute('name', 'RAZON_SOCIAL');
            }

            echo $sxe->asXML();
```